# Writing Apache Zookeeper like service in go

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

I want to write a very simple (but fully functional) Apache Zookeeper like service in go? Where do I start ?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, i think you should understand what zookeeper do first, eg. configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization , also need to know paxos, and so on.
please reference to [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) on github.